# How can we improve "How to ask" help text?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Currently the ["ask" page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) says,

> How To Ask
>
> **Is your question about CiviCRM?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.

No guarantee that changing this help text will make all questions detailed, but it might help. It looks to me like that text is editable. (Is it?)

Relevant:

- [Should CiviCRM version and CMS & version be required when asking a question?](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/should-civicrm-version-and-cms-version-be-required-when-asking-a-question)
- [What are helpful pieces of information to have when answering a CiviCRM SE question?](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-are-helpful-pieces-of-information-to-have-when-answering-a-civicrm-se-quest)

What information would be optimally useful to new site users - communicating how they can best help us to help them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chris's suggested wording](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-can-we-improve-how-to-ask-help-text/169#169) was good, but a little bit rambling. I tightened it up a bit:

> **Is your question about CiviCRM?** If your question is *not* about CiviCRM, you're on the wrong site.
>
> **Detailed questions get informative answers!** Include your CiviCRM version, CMS, screenshots and *any* other details you can think of.
>
> **Show your research.** Let us know what you've learned while trying to find an answer, so we can get right to the point. Tell your story!
>
> New here? **[Take the tour!](/tour)**
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead.
>
> [visit the help center »](/help)
> [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask)

[This is now live.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

> **Ask CiviCRM questions here.** If your question is not about CiviCRM, this is probably not the place for it.
>
> **Detailed questions get informed answers!** Include CiviCRM version, CMS, and other details - this will inform the answers you get. (What's relevant depends on your question, but extra details won't hurt.)
>
> **Show your research.** Let people know what you've learned so far, so the answers reflect this. If it helps tell the story, include screenshots.
>
> **Stack Exchange has a Q&A format.** Ask a specific question, and mark the answer that works for you! You can upvote multiple answers.

Comment: just a suggestion, please add things you think i've missed / critique freely

Comment: I find that action words instead of concepts are more instructive. For example, changing "including CiviCRM version" to "Please include...". Also, I never knew you could add screenshots until way later, so it would be nice if you mentioned. "Feel free to post screenshots" in the "Show your research" question. Otherwise, I like what you have here and can't think of anything else.

Comment: Also, maybe add "How to Ask: Read this first" at the top. I honestly never even noticed this text box before I saw this post.